# python ignoring spelling even though it is right

Tags: python

My python code seems to be ignoring spelling and saying that it has wrong spelling.

I have tried moving around code
changing the input types, this fixed a entry error but began this new error.

```
input("enter month here. spelling and capitalization matter.")
if input == "December" or input == "January" or input == "February":
    print(input, "is in Winter")
elif input == "March" or input == "April" or input == "May":
    print(input, "is in Spring")
elif input == "June" or input == "July" or input == "August":
    print(input, "is in Summer")
elif input == "September" or input == "October" or input == "November":
    print(input, "is in Autumn")
else:
    print("Check spelling")
```

Comment: Please correct your code indentation.

Comment: You aren't assigning a variable to the keyboard input. Input is a built in function which you are trying to compare the string to.

Comment: where should i indent it? i just get indent errors.

Comment: @DylanWyatt please take a look at the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to do this like here:

```
month = input("enter month here. spelling and capitalization matter.")
if month == "December" or month == "January" or month == "February":
    print(month, "is in Winter")
elif month == "March" or month == "April" or month == "May":
    print(month, "is in Spring")
elif month == "June" or month == "July" or month == "August":
    print(month, "is in Summer")
elif month == "September" or month == "October" or month == "November":
    print(month, "is in Autumn")
else:
    print("Check spelling")
input("Press ENTER to quit")
```

What you are missing is that you're not assigning a variable to the keyword `input`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different approach to your problem. There were a few syntax errors in your original post and this might help keep your code easier to read (easier to catch errors).

```
# You can use a dictionary to 'map'
# months to seasons.
seasons = {
    'january': 'Winter',
    'february': 'Winter',
    'march': 'Spring',
    'april': 'Spring',
    'may': 'Spring',
    'june': 'Summer',
    'july': 'Summer',
    'august': 'Summer',
    'september': 'Autumn',
    'october': 'Autumn',
    'november': 'Autumn',
    'december': 'Winter'
}
```

Now you can define a small function that will take advantage of the dictionary above. The user's input will be checked against the **keys** in
`seasons`.

If the **key** is found its **value** can be returned in a formatted string. Rather, they can be returned together as a *key* - *value* pair. You can also call `lower()` in order to allow for a wider range of inputs.

```
def user_prompt():
    """
    Here we ask for the month and use that
    month to do a 'lookup' in the seasons
    dictionary from above.

    :return: (str) formatted month and its season
    """
    month = input("Enter a month here: ")

    # call lower() to resolve capitalization differences
    if month.lower() in seasons.keys():
        return "{} is in the {}".format(month, seasons[month.lower()])
    else:
        return "{} is not a valid month.".format(month)


print(user_prompt())
```

The other advantage to this modular approach is the ability to use this kind of function in a `while` loop—in the event you wanted a user to keep trying to type a correct month.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save `input` in any variable.

```
aa= input("enter month here. spelling and capitalization matter:")
if aa== "December" or aa== "January" or aa== "February":
    print(aa, "is in Winter")
elif aa== "March" or aa== "April" or aa== "May":
    print(aa, "is in Spring")
elif aa== "June" or aa== "July" or aa== "August":
    print(aa, "is in Summer")
elif aa== "September" or aa== "October" or aa== "November":
    Print(aa, "is in Autumn")
else:
    print("Check spelling")
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your input in some variable.
You are using builtin_function_or_method to check if it equals.

```
month = input("enter month here. spelling and capitalization matter.")
if month == "December" or month == "January" or month == "February":
    print(month, "is in Winter")
elif month == "March" or month == "April" or month == "May":
    print(month, "is in Spring")
elif month == "June" or month == "July" or month == "August":
    print(month, "is in Summer")
elif month == "September" or month == "October" or month == "November":
    print(month, "is in Autumn")
else:
    print("Check spelling")
```